# Include Stripe in angular project

Tags: django, angular, stripe-payments

I am working on a website which uses angular for client and django for backend and I want to include stripe for payments. To configure stripe on the backend I have a microservice which runs on docker and accepts the following requests:

- one for creating a stripe customer
  [image: create customer request]
- another one for creating a payment
  [image: initialize payment]

I configured stripe on the client using the provided form as follows:

```
export class PaymentComponent implements OnInit {

  paymentHandler:any = null;

  constructor(private checkoutService: CheckoutService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.invokeStripe();
  }
  
  initializePayment(amount: number) {
    const paymentHandler = (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
      key: 'pk_test_51MKU1wDo0NxQ0glB5HRAxUsR9MsY24POw3YHwIXnoMyFRyJ3cAV6FaErUeuEiWkGuWgAOoB3ILWXTgHA1CE9LTFr00WOT5U5vJ',
      locale: 'auto',
      token: function (stripeToken: any) {
        console.log(stripeToken);
        alert('Stripe token generated!');
        paymentStripe(stripeToken);
      }
    });

    const paymentStripe = (stripeTocken: any) => {
      this.checkoutService.makePayment(stripeTocken).subscribe((data:any) => {
        console.log(data)
      })
    }
  
    paymentHandler.open({
      name: 'Card Details',
      description: 'Introduce the information from your card',
      amount: amount * 100
    });
  }
  
  invokeStripe() {
    if(!window.document.getElementById('stripe-script')) {
      const script = window.document.createElement("script");
      script.id = "stripe-script";
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.src = "https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js";
      script.onload = () => {
        this.paymentHandler = (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
          key: 'pk_test_51MKU1wDo0NxQ0glB5HRAxUsR9MsY24POw3YHwIXnoMyFRyJ3cAV6FaErUeuEiWkGuWgAOoB3ILWXTgHA1CE9LTFr00WOT5U5vJ',
          locale: 'auto',
          token: function (stripeToken: any) {
            console.log(stripeToken)
            alert('Payment has been successfull!');
          }
        });
      }
      window.document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
  }

}
```

The ***makePayment*** method makes a request to the django server sending the stripe tocken.
From the server I need the above requests to the microservice.
My question is **why do I need the configurations from the server as long as all I have to do to perform a payment is to make a request to the microservice?** And where should I use the tocken.

I have also read about webhooks, but I don't really understand the concept and how to use this in my situation.
**Also, do I need to test everything with angular cli? And why?**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It looks like you are using the Legacy Checkout integration, which is (as its name imply) quite old and not recommended. You can learn more about how it works [here](https://stripe.com/docs/legacy-checkout), but I would strongly encourage you to use the newer [Checkout Session](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment) instead.